# clean-up cronjob on docker registry deployed on k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry

please how can I run clean-up cronjob on docker registry deployed on k8s cluster …particularly to delete images that are more than 30 days on the registry

deploy cron job on the same pod with the docker registry

Comment: any update on this ? please feel free to update the status of question if found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Deploy cron job on the same pod with the docker registry

Not sure which **container registry** you are running and setup done.

You have **two** options either you go with **standalone** **Cronjob** with **K8s** or a sidecar container with **Cronjob** inside it.

As you are looking for **cronjob** on the **same POD** you can create one **sidecar** container with **Cronjob** configure inside it and run the container to the same POD of **Docker registry**.

```
 containers:
    - name: ubuntu-sidecar-cronjob-cleanup
      image: ubuntu-docker-with-crontab-running-shell-script
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      env:
        - name: cron
          value: "8 * * * *"
    - image: main-image
      name: main-container
      env:
        - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          value: YOUR_KEY
```

Here is my [shell script](https://github.com/harsh4870/Clean-GCR-Repository/blob/master/cleangcr.sh) you can use for reference and create the **Docker** image to run as **sidecar** container into **POD**.